# How to pass/assign php template value to wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a sample.php template for database interaction. I have created wordpress page to submit data from it. Now, I have identity column and I want to show Idetity value on wordpress textbox. I am able to get that Identity value in my php code in the following way:

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){ $last_id = $conn->insert_id; printf($last_id);
```

It getting Identity Id. Now, I want to assign the said identity id into my wordpress textbox where i choose sample.php as my template.

Comment: Hi there! The stackoverflow community enjoys helping out developers achieve their goals, with the premise of helping one's self first. In that regard, have a look at this [link][1] to help you better formulate your question, show your work and help us help you in general. Thanks!
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks! I have gone through the link.  I will always try to improve question asking skill.

Answer (score 0):

The meta data used in the wp_postmeta table in Wordpress is: _wp_page_template

You can change this value to update the template of a wordpress page.